# get data from firebase using python

Tags: python, firebase

I want to use python and fetch following data from my firebase app

1) get count of firebase event for last day, for last 30 days
2) specify country for (1) as filter and get same data

How can I do this ?
Can you provide some links to get more information on how to fetch various data reported in firebase ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to integrate Firebase in your app with Python is with [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase)

I found this 
https://hackbrightacademy.com/blog/heating-firebase-tutorial-integrate-firebase-app/
very helpfull

Comment: can you give me sample command to get the firebase event data ? Thanks !